# Binding Ilist value with Combobox in datagridview

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a requirement like i have list of values in a List.I need to bind a Combobox in a DataGridView And add the values in the Combobox.

```
   private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            dgvFiles.Rows.Clear();
            dgvFiles.Columns.Clear();
            dgvFiles.Columns.Add("FileName", "File Name");
            dgvFiles.Columns.Add("Size", "File Size");
            dgvFiles.Columns.Add("Extension", "Extension");
            dgvFiles.Columns.Add("Non-OCR Pages", "Non-OCR Pages");
            dgvFiles.Columns.Add("OCR Pages", "OCR Pages");               
            dgvFiles.Columns.Add("Total Pages", "Total Pages");
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn tb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            dgvFiles.Columns.Add(tb);
            tb.Name = "Non-OCR PageNos";
            tb.HeaderText = "Non-OCR PageNos";
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn tb1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            dgvFiles.Columns.Add(tb1);
            tb1.Name = "OCR PageNos";
            tb1.HeaderText = "OCR PageNos";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*.pdf");
            //string[] templist = File.ReadAllLines("d:\\pdfcheck.txt");
            textBox1.Text = null;
            textBox2.Text = null;
            //StreamWriter OpStream = new StreamWriter("d:\\OCR_NonOCR_Report.csv");
            List<int> listNonOcr = new List<int>();
            List<int> listOcr = new List<int>();
           dgvFiles.Rows.Add(f.Name, f.Length, f.Extension, label4.Text.ToString(), label3.Text.ToString(),listNonOcr, listOcr, total.ToString();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.....

```
public class SomeClass
{
  private string name;

  public SomeClass(string name)
  {
     this.name = name;
  }

  public string Name
  {
     get{return name;}
  }

  public object This
  {
     get{return this;}
   }
}

so that you  can specify:

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
column.ValueMember = "Name";
column.ValueMember = "This";
column.DataSource = new List<SomeClass>(new SomeClass[]{new
SomeClass("Fred")});
```